# Error affecting vercel deployment but not a local build

Tags: javascript, reactjs, browserify

I keep getting this error when compiling on Vercel or Heroku, but not on my PC.

```
Module not found: Error: You attempted to import /vercel/path0/node_modules/console-browserify/index.js which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported.
```

This is an error I get when running `npm run build` on Vercel, it does not occur on a local build.

I have tried changing the webpack version (it just gives a different error).
I have no idea where console-browserify is used (apart from react itself).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was resolved by just removing all `console.log`, `console.warn`, etc. from the program!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem deploying on Netlify. I'm using https://github.com/Richienb/node-polyfill-webpack-plugin.

All I have to do is to exclude console-browsify

```
const NodePolyfillPlugin = require("node-polyfill-webpack-plugin")

module.exports = {
    // Other rules...
    plugins: [
        new NodePolyfillPlugin({
            excludeAliases: ["console"]
        })
    ]
}
```